# How can I use the ERP Adapter from Oracle ERP Cloud with Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC)?

Tags: oracle-integration-cloud

I would like to learn about the integration flow and necessary configurations when linking files output from Oracle ERP Cloud's BIP to UCM with Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC) using the ERP Adapter. If anyone has experience with this integration method, I would appreciate their guidance. Additionally, I would like to know about any constraints related to the ERP Adapter.

I would like to know the details of the collaboration flow and the necessary configuration information.
cannot use FTP for network security reasons.